# Why registerController is not inserting data to database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms, model-view-controller, insert

I am new to laravel. I want to insert users data to database using registerController in laravel.

What I have tried is:

register.blade.php

```
@extends('adminlte::auth.auth-page', ['auth_type' => 'register'])

@php( $login_url = View::getSection('login_url') ?? config('adminlte.login_url', 'login') )
@php( $register_url = View::getSection('register_url') ?? config('adminlte.register_url', 'register') )

@if (config('adminlte.use_route_url', false))
    @php( $login_url = $login_url ? route($login_url) : '' )
    @php( $register_url = $register_url ? route($register_url) : '' )
@else
    @php( $login_url = $login_url ? url($login_url) : '' )
    @php( $register_url = $register_url ? url($register_url) : '' )
@endif

@section('auth_header', __('adminlte::adminlte.register_message'))

@section('auth_body')
 

 <?php  $res= DB::table('states')->orderBy('name','asc')->get(); 

 ?>
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register_user') }}" class="registerForm">
                       
 @csrf
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                {{-- First Name field --}}
                

                <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name *" name="first_name" value="" required>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name *" name="last_name" value="" required>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email *" required>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control phoneMask" placeholder="Phone *" name="phone" value="" required>
                    
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-offset-4 submit_btn">

            {{-- Register button --}}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block {{ config('adminlte.classes_auth_btn', 'btn-flat btn-primary') }}">
            <span class="fas fa-user-plus"></span>
            {{ __('adminlte::adminlte.register') }}
        </button>

            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>


@stop

@section('auth_footer')
    <p class="my-0">
        <a href="{{ route('login') }}">
            {{ __('adminlte::adminlte.i_already_have_a_membership') }}
        </a>
    </p>
@stop
```

RegisterController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Auth;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users']
            //'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    /*protected function create(array $data)
    {
        /*return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
        dd($data);
         $user= User::create([
            'first_name'              => $data['first_name'],            
            'last_name'         => $data['last_name'],
            'email'             => $data['email'],
            'password'          => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'mobile'             => $data['phone']
            
        ]);

        // dd($data['password'], $user->password);
       return $user; 
        
}*/
public function registerUsers(Request $request)

{
   
    $first_name=$request->input('first_name');
     $last_name=$request->input('last_name');
       $email=$request->input('email');
         $phone=$request->input('phone');
```

dd($request);
DB::insert('insert into users(first_name,last_name,email,phone)values(?,?,?,?)',[$first_name,$last_name,$email,$phone]);

```
}
    }
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::post('/register_user', 'Auth\RegisterController@registerUsers')->name('register_user');
```

Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements AuditableContract
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
    use SoftDeletes;
    use Auditable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name','email','phone','device_token','password','approved','added_by','removed','removed_by','deleted_at'];
}
```

When I try to submit this form, it is not inserting data to database and is showing HTTP error 500 and couldn't handle request.
What my form looks like

[image: Form]

How to fix and insert data to database.

Comment: First thing you have to do is checking error logs (server logs, php logs and laravel logs).

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei How to do so

Comment: laravel logs - storage/logs/laravel.log most of the errors will be recorded in this file

Comment: @yadu siva das ,@RouhollahMazarei Is there any other method to fix this. I want to insert data to users table

Comment: give me a sec, i'll write the function for you

Comment: Why have you commented out the `create` and added a `registerUsers` method? This will cause the validation, event and login functionality to be bypassed.

Comment: Also, have you checked the Laravel log (mentioned above)?

Comment: @Binsha Hello, Have you checked the form action URL?  It should be `/register_user`.
Please inspect the registration form and check from action URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the cross-fire request forgery to your form. Generally I get this error when I forget it.
Add it like that in your view:

```
<?php  $res= DB::table('states')->orderBy('name','asc')->get(); ?>
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register_user') }}" class="registerForm">
 
@csrf             

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {{-- First Name field --}}
```

Comment: Its already included

Comment: @Binsha where ? I don't see it in your view. I even run a key word searched.

Answer (score 0):

Route

```
 Route::post('/test', 'Auth\RegisterController@test')->name('test');
```

Auth\RegisterController

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
. 
.
.


public function test ( Request $request){

        $rules = array(
        'first_name' => 'required', 'string', 'max:255',
        // add validation rules here
    );

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
    if ($validator->passes()) {
        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $request->input('first_name');

        //copy above line and add remaining fields.

        $user->save();
        return redirect()->back()->with(array('message' => 'user added.'));
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
}
```

Comment: Change route name,url and function name

Comment: Not working , showing same error as could not handle request.

Comment: I am using adminlte

Comment: Its not working. I am using adminlte

Comment: by default password is a mandatory field. change that in DB, and try again

Comment: Have changed , but still its not working.

Comment: post the error message

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps

1. make sure your request received by the desired route
2. make sure you have passed validation
3. then input data like this

DB::table('post')->insert([

```
DB::table('posts')->insert([
'name_name' => \request()->name,
'last_name' => \request()->last_name,
'email' => \request()->email,
'phone' => \request()->phone,
]);
```

Comment: Not working . Not inserting to database

Comment: please follow the steps I defined and determine where is the problem?

Comment: Not inserting to database

Comment: till which step your code works? send the output of that step and share the code after that step

Comment: Not working till now dd($request) is working , but not inserting

Comment: When I try to insert , it is not inserting to database

Comment: Please, share the output of the step where code work well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239685/discussion-between-binsha-and-mansoor-kochy).